# Meteor App Mongo Collection doesn't load on Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb, google-chrome, meteor

I've created a *Meteor 1.3* test app to demonstrate the problem I'm facing. It's online at [grido.bvodola.webfactional.com](http://grido.bvodola.webfactional.com). This is a very simple todo app.

This app works well almost everywhere. Except on some of the devices I tested and only on mobile versions of Google Chrome. The versions I tested were 50.0.2661.89 and 47.0.2526.83.

**The issue is**: the mongo collection (which is just a bunch of tasks hosted at [mlab.com](http://mlab.com)) takes a really long time to load or is not loaded at all.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? This has happened to this little app and also to this other app I'm developing for a client.
I don't even know where to start looking.

Any contribution would be very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Code for the app (just for the reference):

**client/main.html**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Grido</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    {{ #each task in tasks }}
      {{ > taskItem task=task }}
    {{ /each }}
  </ul>
  <form>
    <p>Task: <input type="text" class="task-title" name="title"></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Add Task</button></p>
  </form>
</body>

<template name="taskItem">
  <li>{{ task.title }} <a href="#" class="delete-task">&times;</a></li>
</template>
```

**client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Tasks} from '../imports/api/tasks';

import './main.html';

Template.body.helpers({
    'tasks': function() {
        return Tasks.find();
    }
});

Template.body.events({

    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Tasks.insert({
            title: $(".task-title").val()
        }, function(e,id) {
            if(!e)
                console.log(id);
            else
                console.log(e);
        });
        $(".task-title").val('');
    }
});

Template.taskItem.events({
    'click .delete-task': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Tasks.remove(this.task._id);
    }
});
```

**imports/api/tasks.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '../imports/api/tasks';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

Comment: At least for me, your server refuses the websocket connection, so it falls back to XHR long polling. This may add delay, but should not cause complete failure. That said, I don't experience the same failure to load you described (chrome mobile v50.0.2661.89), takes ~3sec to load and normally very little delay for data sync between devices.

Comment: @MasterAM, thanks for the insight. This led me right to what I guess is the root of the problem. I don't know much about the difference betweeb websockets and XHR long polling, but I uploaded the same app to heroku on grido.herokuapp.com and it ran perfectly on the devices that showed errors in the webfaction version. A quick look at the Console on the Heroku version shows no failure in the ws connection. So I guess there is a relation, right?

Comment: Just to add another useful information, I uploaded the app to a **websockets custom app** in *WeFaction* and it ran perfectly as well, no ws connection error and had no problem  showing the data on the mobile browser. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to read that!